# What is the best way to replace the buttons inside a car remote chip so that it can be controlled via Arduino?

Tags: button, switch, remote-control

I have a car remote that looks like the following

[image]

I would like to replace the buttons with some sort of switch or relay that can be programmatically controlled via an arduino unit. Would a simple relay switch work if I de-solder the buttons? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you do not have to remove the switches ... you can just bridge them with relay contacts ... it may also be possible to do this without relays .... measure the voltage between ground and each side of the switch ... use battery negative terminal as ground ... post the result

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, I will post it soon. May I ask what you are thinking with regards to no relays?

Comment: I currently have the device on me and am measuring the voltage. Should I be pressing the button when measuring voltage?

Comment: Thanks, I will do that, is the point is to find sets are the input/output terminals and how much voltage it is taking in? Should I contain a current or resistance reading as well?

Comment: I measured it, and found that the voltage was 2.97 V from a black probe placed on negative battery side and a red probe on one of the 4 contacts (the one across from it read 0). The voltage of the battery itself was found to be 3.01 V.  Thank you

Comment: the 2.97 V pin is most likely the data pin ... it probably has a pullup resistor to +V  .... pressing the switch shorts the input to ground .... you can use a transistor in an open-collector configuration to short the input to ground ... the switch does not need to be removed ... you could solder a wire to one of the round test pads

Comment: Will I create problems if I directly use a switch to bridge the two pins of the button without a resistor? Thank you for the config, how can i tell which test pad is the right one?

Comment: the button directly bridges the two pins when you press it   .......... there is only 10 test pads ... use the voltmeter and press a button

Comment: Thank you, I believe I found it. The battery provides 3 V, while my arduino has 3.3 V. Do you think using 3.3V instead of the battery will create issues?

Comment: probably nor, but it is not possible to be absolutely certain without seeing the datasheet for the control chip

Comment: If you put a resistor (100 to 1000 ohm) between the output of the Arduino and the 2.97 V side of the button, then you can pull the Arduino's output to ground to mimic a button press. In the worst case, the 3.3 V on Arduino's output and the 2.97 V on the switch would be connected through the, say 100 ohm, resistor. The current would be less than 3 mA, which both Arduino and the microcontroller on the fob should be able to handle. This assumes the switch was configured with a pull-up resistor on the fob, in which case its pull-up resistance would most likely be much higher than 100 ohm.